# Problem with USB wireless mouse

Tags: wireless-networking, mouse

Recently I have started having problems with my wireless mouse ([Wireless Optical Mouse MI-4910D](http://www.trust.com/15313)).

Sometimes when I start my PC or during a game the pointer/arrow stops moving. When the PC boots the pointer is locked in the center of the screen. If I'm lucky it helps to change the USB wireless adapter from port 1 to port 2 but sometimes this trick doesn't work and I have to restart my PC to get the mouse to work again.

Like you can see in the product web page this mouse don't have a driver but only a tool to solve some problems.

Answer (score 0):

... Did you try changing the batteries?

Comment: yes the battery are full charged

Answer (score 0):

For any USB related issues I would try the following:

1. Any other wireless USB receivers - keyboards, bluetooth/network adapters, etc?
2. Outdated m/b drivers?
3. Batteries running low, as suggested before? Also when changing the batteries, do not leave it for the last moment and clean the battery contacts inside the mouse or any corrosion as the batteries tend to leak.
4. Mouse drivers and/or manufacturer software issues?

And finally - does the mouse operate fine while not gaming? Could it be a game setting?

Hope this helps!

Regards,
Taavi